# How do I decode a websocket packet?

Tags: sockets, tcp, websocket, decode

I'm using Wireshark packet analyzer & when I filter for all "Websocket" packets I see what I am sending /receiving to the host. When I check individual packets mine always show as [MASKED], but you can 'Umask Payload' which shows the data in clear text that looks like this:

```
<IC sid="52ccc752-6080-4668-8f55-662020d83979" msqid="120l93l9l114l30l104"/>
```

However, if I 'Follow TCP stream & look at that same packet, the data shows up as encoded in some way like this:

```
....K#....../...y@..|...}...f...s...~...}...{G..r...kN.."G..z...r...'...'...z...d.
```

The problem is all Websocket packets I receive from the host come as encoded, it is NOT SSL & I can't figure out how to decode them, I have no idea what they are even encoded as (but yet my browser can decode it).

I assume that whatever method they are coming back to me as encoded data is the same method that my data is encoded when I use 'Follow TCP stream'.

Can someone please help me figure out how to decode the data the host is sending me? See host data below

```
~.^jVpZc9y4Ef4ryFQ5+yJpeB+JJJdmNPI6G++mrN249kkFkuChIQmG5Fgj//p0AyAJypzxyi5T6P76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```

Comment: That looks a lot like base64.

Comment: I tried a bunch of base64 decoders and they didn't work. Can you give it a shot?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? I get binary stuff that doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: (Do you mean you couldn't get a base64 decoder to decode it? Or do you mean that the output you got from the decoder didn't make sense?) The data is [masked](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2012/01/websockets-with-rfc-6455/) and you need to unmask it to make sense of it.

Answer (score 2):

Client to server data is XORed with a mask (included in the dataframe). Some people suggest this is in order to throw off bad caching mechanisms responding to new websocket requests with server messages from older sessions. The masking makes sure that even messages containing identical data will appear differently to applications that do not understand websockets.

Also note that there are many different size options for the headers themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to RFC 6455 Section 5 which defines the masking/unmasking process for payloads sent from the client to the server.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455

If you find any freeware VBA code to do the job of forming packets let me know! :-)